# Live online presentation using a pdf file

Tags: web-apps, pdf

I want to give an online lesson to a class of about 40 people. I will be talking and I want them to see a presentation at the same time. The presentation is a pdf file (beamer).  I know I can share my screen but I am not happy with this solution because

1. My bandwidth is limited, I cannot reliably stream video
2. The image quality of screen sharing isn't the same
3. It seems like a waste of resources (it's a 45 minute talk with a 500Kb pdf file...)

I am looking for a solution that would ideally:

1. Allow me to upload a pdf file and provide me with a "public" link
2. I can go through the pages of the file and everyone with the public link can see the page that I am currently seeing.

I know of solutions that can do this with powerpoint files but the material is ready and conversion to powerpoint is not an option.
BigBlueButton can do what I am asking but it shows a white screen in between page changes and this spoils the effect of a beamer presentation.

I am open to self-hosted solutions but would like to avoid screensharing (mainly for the extra bandwidth). I could spend around 10$/month.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! As this site doesn't cover [howtos](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/185), I assume you wanted to ask for software. Are you open to self-hosted solutions (this could e.g. be done with Screensharing in Jitsi Meet)? And if it comes to paid solutions, how much would you be willing to spend?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, that is what I meant. I am open to self-hosted solutions but would like to avoid screensharing (mainly for the extra bandwidth). I could spend around 10$/month.

Comment: Screensharing of a static pic shouldn't cause that much bandwidth use. You could try that with any public Jitsy Meet instance to see for yourself. AFAIK Jitsi Meet allows to specify the window to share, so you can easily limit that to the PDF itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a service ([beamium.com](https://www.beamium.com/)) that does what I wanted but one of the comments suggested screen sharing *(at least in Jitsy Meet)* doesn't cause that much bandwidth.